# Display the text back to TextPref

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-edittext

Need to display back the text input provided in Text Preference

```
    PreferenceCategory generalPrefCat = new PreferenceCategory(this);
    generalPrefCat.setTitle("General Settings");
    root.addPreference(generalPrefCat);

    // Your Name preference
    EditTextPreference namePref = new EditTextPreference(this);
    namePref.setDialogTitle("Your Name");
    namePref.setKey("yourname_preference");
    namePref.setTitle("Your Name");        
    generalPrefCat.addPreference(namePref);
```

Need to display the name entered as summary.namePref.setsummary("Santosh").
First time if its not entered nothing should be displayed.

```
   SharedPreferences myPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
   namePref.setSummary(myPreference.getString("yourname_preference", "")));
```

How to I get the input string and display it back?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after but I'll give it a shot. If you wan't to get a specific string from settings.getString if there is no saved string under that key, you can just add that string as the second parameter in the method. Like this:

```
mySettings.getString("user_string", "this_is_the_default_string");
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, please try to make your question clearer.

Comment: @Emian,I need to display the entered text in namePref dialog. Default summary can be set via namePref.setSummary("Enter the username"). I want to set the summary with the entered text.[link](http://www.gadgets.apnafundaz.com/wp-content/gadgetstore/2010/11/View-Contacts-Settings-Review-Social-Phonebook-on-Xperia-X10-with-EclairAndroid-2.1-Automagical-Experience1.png) , in this screenshot, email id is the displayed based on what user has entered.